# armv7 error when importing Reachable

Tags: ios, ios8, arm, reachability

Not sure how to diagnose the errors shown below. These only occurred when trying to use Apples "Reachable" import. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Listings/ReadMe_txt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007324-ReadMe_txt-DontLinkElementID_10

[image]

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Is `Reachability.m` in `Compile Sources`?

Comment: No, I haven't dealt with the .m file. I have now and it works great. I'm not sure how I missed that! Write that as an official answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check to make sure that `Reachability.m` is listed in `Compile Sources`.